# Wordpress Upload images to folder and Db link even subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

Hi this is what i wast to accomplish

In a folder i want a picture to be placed (testimage.jpg)
and in in some custom way i want this to get link to wp_usermeta

Extra feature

---

that place a userid,houseid,headertext,text,Image 
So i seperate the image and text that different house have.

So when i have this a customer can put up there house and show picture of it.
and a customer can have multiply housese thats the houseid.

---

This is the code to just upload an image to a folder and a referense in the db/image tabel.
I have not program so mutch php.
i have used like this.

```
add_action('the_post','test');
function test(){
$user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $user->data->ID;
}
```

this code i have on the test page

```
echo '<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-`data">';`
echo 'Select image to upload:';
echo '<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

and i have the upload.php

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','JPG','JPEG');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], `$targetFilePath)){`
            // Insert image file name into database          
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, `uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");`



            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded `successfully.";`
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your `file.";`
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are `allowed to upload.';`
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

but i just get
404: Sidan kan inte hittas

```
http://wordpress.test/test/upload.php 
--the /test/ is a page and i dont know where to put the upload.php to work.
```

So i havent got to the place where i want to insert userid,house id to seperate them. I dont know where to put the upload.php

I have followed a guide

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-uCOATMqdk

how to upload images to db
with an folder inside my wordpress.test folder.
thats called    upload_store_image_in_database_php
and in there i put a 
folder called uploads
dbconfig.php 
index.php
upload.php
```

when i go to

```
http://wordpress.test/upload_store_image_in_database_php/
```

when everything works, and i get a picture on the uploadfolder and a db link. But i cant adapt the code to wordpress

Comment: have you created a template for test page?

Comment: Dont know how to do that =/

Comment: I have now upload a new template and inserted the
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image File to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

Comment: Same problmen 404 no page found when pressing upload image